# Wifi not working in fresh ubuntu 16.04 with acpi=off

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, acpi

I know similar questions are already there, but I went through almost many of those and could not figure out how to solve it. I badly need my wifi up and running.

I could load ubuntu by using "acpi=off" in boot parameters and then even in live ubuntu and even after installation, wifi networks are not showing up and my airplane mode is always on even if I turn it off, later it will toggle to on.

rfkill list

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

I looked for any hardware switch, but mine is "hp pavillion 13 a201", has only airplane mode switch which doesn't do anything.

sudo lshw -class network

```
   *-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 3160
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 83
   serial: 34:e6:ad:b5:9a:c3
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-52-generic firmware=17.352738.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:26 memory:c1100000-c1101fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 08
   serial: d0:bf:9c:9e:54:99
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:23 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1004000-c1004fff memory:c1000000-c1003fff
```

lsmod | grep -e lap -e wmi

```
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
DeviceName: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 802.11ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 [8086:0070]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm                   598016  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
arc4                   16384  2
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
iwlmvm                360448  0
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
mac80211              761856  1 iwlmvm
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
uvcvideo               90112  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45056  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
cryptd                 24576  3   ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
hid_sensor_accel_3d    16384  0
hid_sensor_incl_3d     16384  0
hid_sensor_rotation    16384  0
hid_sensor_magn_3d     16384  0
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     16384  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
hid_sensor_trigger     16384  10       hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  5  hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
intel_cstate           16384  0
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_hda_codec         135168  4   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
industrialio           65536  8   hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,industrialio_triggered_buffer,kfifo_buf
snd_hda_core           86016  5   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
videodev              180224  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               110592  4   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
hid_sensor_iio_common    16384  6   hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
hid_multitouch         20480  0
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
joydev                 20480  0
iwlwifi               229376  1 iwlmvm
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
input_leds             16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
cfg80211              581632  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
snd                    86016  21     snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
serio_raw              16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
autofs4                40960  2
hid_sensor_custom      20480  0
hid_sensor_hub         20480  8    hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_iio_common,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_custom
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 53248  0
hid                   122880  4   hid_sensor_hub,hid_generic,usbhid,hid_multitouch
i915                 1314816  112
video                  40960  1 i915
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        167936  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   368640  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
psmouse               139264  0
r8169                  81920  0
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mii                    16384  1 r8169
rtsx_pci               57344  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

I have tried

```
rfkill unblock all
```

but nothing, Is it because I turned off acpi?

also

sudo ifconfig wlo1 up

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

sudo modprobe hp-wmi

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'hp_wmi': No such device
```

++added

dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    9.728583] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't find IRQ for PCI INT A; please try using pci=biosirq
[   10.435598] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.459231.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   10.969645] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   10.973894] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   10.974192] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   10.974240] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   11.067718] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   12.214623] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

I would appreciate a lot if someone could look in to it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Airplane mode turns all radios off, that's what it does.

Comment: Ya,  but I cant turn it off since it just toggle back to on. I need my wifi up and running.  Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: Please run: `sudo modprobe hp-wmi` and then see if the airplane mode switch works. If there is an error or warning, please post it.

Comment: I have edited my question with the result.It says: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'hp_wmi': No such device

Comment: @chili555 and MichaelBay . Thank you for spending your quality time for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a day long search and troubleshoot, I finally found a hack for all my problems.
Since I used

```
acpi=off
```

in boot parameters, I didn't have battery status and those power management options. In some computers like mine it turns off the wifi also.

So instead of using acpi=off, another parameter has to be found out. This could depend on your system, but in my case no other parameter mentioned through out the net worked, thats why I installed with "acpi=off". But

```
acpi_osi=
```

replacing acpi=off will solve the problem, atleast in my case. Yes, There is nothing to the right of =.

Hope this will help someone in future.